# Searching with a multilist field in Lucene.NET

Tags: .net, lucene.net, sitecore

I am using [Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/) and the [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for indexing content.

While performing the search lucene does not give the results from the multilist field.

Comment: What exactly is being asked here, what do you mean by "multilist field"?

Comment: Could you please provide more information: indexer configuration + search code. Also, responses to this question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848229/how-to-find-related-items-by-tags-in-lucene-net

Comment: actually am using sitecore cms for my website.. the search is performed with the use of lucene.. when i search a word in my site, it searches the sub items and shows the URL of the sub item, but the text is actually placed in the main page (aspx page), but in sitecore the aspx page is dynamically created (at run time), there is no such physical page in sitecore.. so now how can i perform the search and how can i get the exact URL of the word, if it is placed in the sub items. –

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you take a look at Alex Shyba's [Advanced Database Crawler](http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/) which does a good job at using Lucene.NET with Sitecore. [Here's a blog post](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html) on his blog introducing this new tool.

Also, [take a look at his post](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/12/treelist-not-registering-links-in.html) on an issue with Treelist fields not registering links to other items. I also used a multilist (treelist to be specific) field for the scenario you mentioned and this trick seemed to help. My question to him actually may have spurred his blog post as he emailed me the trick then posted it. This may or may not help you depending on how you're integrating Sitecore and Lucene.NET.

**Note**: depending on the version of Sitecore you're using, the Link Database might need to get updated to handle these multilist associations to other items. Alex also has another [blog post on code to help with that](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/09/optimizing-sitecore-link-database.html).

Comment: actually am using sitecore cms for my website.. the search is performed with the use of lucene.. when i search a word in my site, it searches the sub items and shows the URL of the sub item, but the text is actually placed in the main page (aspx page), but in sitecore the aspx page is dynamically created (at run time), there is no such physical page in sitecore.. so now how can i perform the search and how can i get the exact URL of the word, if it is placed in the sub items.